# Limit downloading of maven dependencies when version in open end range

Tags: java, maven, nexus, dependency-management

I have a multi module maven project with a parent POM which defines a few common dependencies as part of the dependency management as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example-commons-core</artifactId>
    <version>(1.2,)</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example-commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>(1.3,)</version>
</dependency>
```

I have added this version format to avoid permanently update versions in the POM, when a new version of the core library is created.

My problem is that by each maven build, maven will check up all repositories for new version for each dependency I got following log entries:

```
Downloading from snapshots: https://example.com/repository/snapshots/com.example/example-commons-core/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from release: https://example.com/repository/release/com.example/example-commons-core/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from 3rdparty: https://example.com/repository/3rdparty/com.example/example-commons-core/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from central: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.example/example-commons-core/maven-metadata.xml
```

1. My question is can I do the checks for example monthly?
2. How to avoid that maven tries to check my own dependencies on maven central repository?

Comment: The checking is exactly caused by using version ranges. Furthermore your build is not reproducible anymore. I can strongly recommend to prevent using of version ranges. Use fixed versions ...If the repositories are checked for your own dependencies in your build I would assume you have a problem in your build...

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Yes, I have to agree with you it was not the best idea to use open range versions. I have changed my POM to the fexed version. Thanks very much again!

Answer (score 1):

The modern way to solve the problem is to avoid version ranges but use the versions maven plugin (like `versions:use-latest-releases`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm just evaluating which plugins can help me with this.